# Remove multiple dictionary value from a list using Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

My data is as follow

```
dd=[{'id':'aa','age':22,'data':{},'background':{}},
      {'id':'bb','age':23,'data':{},'background':{}},
      {'id':'cc','age':24,'data':{},'background':{}},
      {'id':'dd','age':25,'data':{},'background':{}},
      {'id':'ee','age':26,'data':{},'background':{}}      
     ]
```

How to remove several responses based on id? I have almost 100 responses that need to be removed.

As example:

```
id = ' aa bb cc '
```

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension to filter out the data you do not want.
However, you should not use the name `id`

```
dd = [item for item in dd if item['id'] not in id]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **filter**, and **lambda** functions here,

`dd = list(filter(lambda x : x["id"] not in a, dd))`